# Math.random range negative

Tags: java

If I were to do:
Math.random() * 4-2

Would this get me a range of (-2,2), 2 being exclusive? I think this is right but I rarely get positive numbers (yes, I know this is a random algorithm and we would have to generate randomly infinitely for it to *feel* but I just want to make sure)

New Question

If I wanted all random rational numbers from -1 to 1, both bounds inclusive, would this line work:
Math.random() * 2.0000000000000001 - 1;

I looked up that a double past the decimal point can store about 52 bits would this about 16 digits, which is about the number of 0's past this point.

The project I'm working on is estimating digits of pi using a Monte Carlo simulation, and if you know anything about that then maybe you understand why I'm asking all this stuff.

Comment: When you say you rarely get positive numbers, could you post the code that's producing these bad values? That seems like the real (and more interesting) question here.

Comment: do also not that you are getting sudo random numbers from the java random API.  please see this link for an example https://boallen.com/random-numbers.html

Comment: how many numbers do you generate? 10? 100? 1000?

Comment: These are my method calls and results:   System.out.println((Math.random() * 4) - 3);
-0.2903562832149409
System.out.println((Math.random() * 4) - 3);
-2.7248500915286704
System.out.println((Math.random() * 4) - 3);
0.18566196065911544
System.out.println((Math.random() * 4) - 3);
-1.553330265708389
System.out.println((Math.random() * 4) - 3);
-1.7421466754557677
System.out.println((Math.random() * 4) - 3);
-1.9157078132835794
System.out.println((Math.random() * 4) - 3);
-0.6260164010114062
System.out.println((Math.random() * 4) - 3);
-1.8549195133255991
The limit I'm allowed.

Comment: So is it `-2` or `-3`?  You've asked about `-2`, but the code in your comment has `-3`.  (And please don't put more than one line of code in comments - edit the question).

Comment: It's -2. -3 is a mistake. I think it to late to edit the previous though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would this get me a range of (-2,2), 2 being exclusive?

Yes, `Math.random() * 4-2` gives you 4 possibilities at the range of -2 to 1.

You will need more runs to check the distribution..

```
int[] occ = new int[4];
for(int x=0; x<1000000; x++){
    int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 4)-2;
    occ[rand+2] ++;
}

System.out.println("Occurrences for -2: " + occ[0]/10000.0 + "%");
System.out.println("Occurrences for -1: " + occ[1]/10000.0 + "%");
System.out.println("Occurrences for 0: " + occ[2]/10000.0 + "%");
System.out.println("Occurrences for 1: " + occ[3]/10000.0 + "%");
```

A test of 1 million runs shows that the random numbers are quite well distributed:

```
Occurrences for -2: 24.9779%
Occurrences for -1: 25.0338%
Occurrences for 0: 24.971%
Occurrences for 1: 25.0173%
```

Comment: Those parentheses are important.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() gives back a value in the range of [0,1.0) so your expression should give back values [-2.0, 2.0) where 2.0 is exclusive and -2.0 is inclusive.

Math.random() is a pseudorandom number generator, so that could account for your trend towards negative numbers. You'll want to look at implementations for truly random number generation if you want a better distribution of values.

Comment: I doubt whether the lack of true randomness is responsible for any significant bias towards negative numbers.  To me, it seems a little more likely that OP has made a mistake.